# Dribbble color palette to Sketch app

Tags: color, sketch-app, palette, dribbble

I've downloaded dribbble color palette and wanted to install it on Sketch (version 50). Is it possible to do that? How to install color palettes on Sketch?

ps. I also have Sketch Palettes plugin installed.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to get the [Dribbble Sketch Palette](https://github.com/amiechen/dribbble-sketch-palette) extension for Firefox and Chrome, that will let you download a .sketchpalette file directly from dribbble.